# Django class based views, what to override to write to an excel file?

Tags: django, export-to-excel, django-class-based-views

I have an application using Django's class based views.

I want to write to an excel file. What method should I be overriding? render_to_repsonse works, but it seems like I may be calling a lot of other stuff that I don't need (pagination for example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overriding `render_to_response` sounds ok to me. Pagination is optional in the `ListView` - if you don't specify `paginate_by` in your class then it won't do any pagination.

Django will probably not spend a significant amount of time on CBV hooks like `paginate_by` that you do not use. Unless performance is a real issue, and you can see that Django is spending significant time calling stuff you don't need, then I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: I guess its because I am sub classing an HTML ListView, so pagination and template names make sense in that context, but not when generating an excel.

Comment: Pagination in ListView is optional, it won't spend meaningful time on it if you don't specify `paginate_by`.